# Azure pipelines replaces "sa" with "***" - how can I configure this?

Tags: azure-pipelines

So, our build pipelines on visualstudio.com have all the substrings "sa" replaced with "***" in all  log messages - so for instance, if you execute a command with the flag "--no-save", it will be printed in the logs as "--no-***ve".

I'm pretty sure it's a misguided attempt to obfuscate secrets ('sa' being, you know, the default admin user in SQL), but I couldn't find anywhere in our config where we'd do this obfuscation ourselves. Is this default behaviour? How can it be controlled?

Comment: I tried this similar command on my Command Line task, but did not see the message like yours. Do you mind share your log here?

Comment: Can't share the full log. Here's a small, random part of it: https://pastebin.com/HHf7f5AW

Comment: It's the same, as early as "git checkout": https://imgur.com/a/KcFIs02

Comment: Did you check in the variables if there is a secret variable with this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your log shared, I have figured it out. This issue should caused by your **secret variable** configuration.

In details, for example, if you set an variable names `NA`, and its value is `sa`. And then, you set this variable as secret variable. At this time, while you execute this pipeline, all of words which has "`sa`" will be replaced with "`***`".

[image]

> Is this default behaviour? How can it be controlled?

So, for this question, this is not a default behavior by Azure Devops. This should because your secret variable configured.

In addition, you don't need worry about this. This is just be encrypted with RSA. It will not affect your normal variable passed and build running.

But, if your build configured with YAML. You need to pay attention about it. Please refer to this doc: [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables). For using secret variable in YAML, **Map your secrets into environment variables** is the correct way.

Comment: Yes, this was it - apparently VSTS does a "search and replace everywhere"  with the contents of the secret variables. It was easy enough to locate the variable with teh DB Username & mark it as "non-secret", but it's ... well, a bit of a surprising behaviour, for me.

Comment: Yes, same with you, I also very confused about this. And also, I found that it does not has affect about number, just occur on string. I suggest you can report this issue to  [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21). This community has high priority can give you the exact investigation.